# How to work with duplicates within a list where you have to replace elements based on decisions?

Tags: python

We get 8 numbers and have to input them into a list.
we then have run the element through decisions and replace them based on the outcome. the decisions are:

> - If the value of the element is less than the array index, the element must be replaced with the index plus ten.
> - If the value of the element is equal to the index, the element must be doubled.
> - If the value of the element is greater than the index, the element must be replaced by the index squared.

```
    array = []
    array1 = []
    for i in range(8):
        num = int(input())
        array.append(num)

    for j in array:
        x = 0
        r = array.index(j)
        if j < r:
            x += r + 10
            array1.append(x)
        elif j == r:
            x += j + j
            array1.append(x)
        elif j > r:
            x += r * r
            array1.append(x)
        else:
            pass

    print(array)
    print(array1)
```

input:

```
0
3
4
6
5
4
2
3
```

Expected Output:

```
[0, 3, 4, 6, 5, 4, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 15, 16, 17]
```

My Output:

```
[0, 3, 4, 6, 5, 4, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 4, 16, 1]
```

Comment: What's the point of `r = array.index(j)`...?

Comment: `x = array[j]; array1.append(j + 10 if x < j else x * 2 if x == j else j**2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are finding the index using `index` method over the list, it returns the first occurrence index.

Use `enumerate` method to get index while iterating.

```
array = []
array1 = []
for i in range(8):
    num = int(input())
    array.append(num)

for r, j in enumerate(array):
    x = 0
    if j < r:
        x += r + 10
        array1.append(x)
    elif j == r:
        x += j + j
        array1.append(x)
    elif j > r:
        x += r * r
        array1.append(x)
    else:
        pass

print(array)
print(array1)
```